# Accessing native Android API in Nativescript fails with "Property 'pdf' does not exist on type 'typeof graphics'"

Tags: android, pdf, nativescript

I am trying to access the native Android android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer in my Nativescript application:

```
var pdfrenderer = android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
```

This results in the error "Property 'pdf' does not exist on type 'typeof graphics'".

I can access e.g. the native Android widget Toast though:

```
var Toast = android.widget.Toast;
```

Am I missing something? Can you really access the complete native Android API from Nativescript?

I am using Nativescript Typescript (no Angular) with the latest versions as of today (nativescript 2.5.2, tns-core-modules 2.5.1, tns-android 2.5.0).

My goal is to display a PDF from the local device in my Nativescript app. I am not even sure if that is possible on Android. The Nativescript plugin that I found does not seem to support that although the underlying barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer seems to have a method called "pdfView.fromFile(File)".

Comment: I am using the same versions as you, and had no trouble accessing the `pdf` namespace, it also lists all available classes (`PdfRenderer`, as well as `PdfDocument`). Can you verify that no evident errors occurred during the build?

Comment: On what API level device do you see this error? android.graphics.pdf was added in API level 19.

Comment: @Eddy the lowest that metadata will be generated for is API 22, meaning JavaScript will know about the pdf namespace, while runtime on device of lower API level a Java runtime error will be thrown.

Comment: I am getting an error already in Visual Studio Code: [ts] Property 'pdf' does not exist on type 'typeof graphics'.

I am running the app directly on a device with Android 7.1.1

Comment: @pkanev cool. I thought he meant runtime ;)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I am getting  [ts] Property 'pdf' does not exist on type 'typeof graphics' in Visual Studio Code and subsequently "Property 'pdf' does not exist on type 'typeof graphics'" during the build

Comment: @user2338826 that is an error thrown by the TypeScript compiler, it doesn't know of the existence of the `android` objects, so you could either `declare var android: any` and proceed, or generate android sdk typings that will also provide "intellisense" while coding. First make sure you comment out the line that produces the error, so that the TypeScript compiler doesn't fail the build, then run `tns run/build android --androidTypings`. That will output `android.d.ts` which you may have to reference manually in references.d.ts. Happy coding!